# Как задать количество в веденных цифр в ANTLR4

Tags: java, antlr

Для ограничения ввода четырех цифр в лексическом анализаторе Lex используется следующая конструкция: [0-9]{4}. Как ограничить ввод, так что бы ввести можно было только четыре в ANTLR4?

Answer (score 0):

Ввести каждую цифру отдельно

```
long_num
 : NUM NUM NUM NUM
 ;

NUM
 : '0'..'9'
 ;
```

или можно использовать [предикаты](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/predicates.md)

```
long_num
 : {input.LT(1).getText().length() == 20}? NUM
 ;

NUM
 : '0'..'9'
 ;
```

Comment: А если их не 4 а 20, тогда нужно 20 раз вводить?